# How to modify the default 'sender' and 'subject' in cronjob failure email?

Tags: cron

I setup a cronjob that sends me email on failure. The problem is it's coming from `Cron Daemon` and the subject is `Cron <ubuntu@ip-10-100-21-10> /home/ubuntu/neo/bin/backup-test.sh >> /home/ubuntu/neo/logs/log-test.out`

The way I did it is using this line: `MAILTO="my-email@gmail.com"`

How to modify the `sender` and `subject` to make it a bit cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

I have following lines end of my backup script to send email out with log gathered before.

```
mailbody=${log}
echo "From: Backup xx <backup@gensand.box>" > /tmp/backupmail
echo "To: gen@riddi.eu" >> /tmp/backupmail
echo "Subject: [BACKUP] Failure report for $(hostname)" >> /tmp/backupmail
echo "" >> /tmp/backupmail
cat ${mailbody} >> /tmp/backupmail
cat /tmp/backupmail | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up with something similar:

`
#!/bin/sh

email=someone@gmail.com

report() {
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "Error:\n$error" | mail -s "Neo4j backup fail" $email
    exit 1
  fi
}

error="$(path/myExcecutable-bin 2>&1 > /dev/null)"
report
error="$(foobar 2>&1 > /dev/null)"
report
`

I can't figure out how to format this ):